# Flag plagiarism on OP-deleted post?

Tags: discussion, flags, plagiarism

Periodically (including just now) I'll come across plagiarism where the post has been downvoted, commented on calling out the plagiarism, and subsequently deleted by the OP. *(In this case — shudder — copying and pasting the HTML from a w3schools reference page into an answer. As a code block. Yikes.)*

Presumably at least one of the people downvoting and/or commenting has flagged the post with a mod flag with the word "plagiarism" in it, triggering the special handling of those in the mod queue. But I don't *know* that, of course; we mere mortals can't see flags on posts.

Is it useful in terms of dealing with repeat plagiarists for me to flag the post even though it's been self-deleted? (This does not apply, of course, to posts deleted by a mod or the community, only ones the plagiarist deletes themselves, realizing they've been caught.)